# How can I skip the fourth element in a float4 when using cublas sgemv?

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, thrust, cublas

Part of the code I am working on requires to perform a Matrix vector multiplication as fast as possible, i.e using an optimized third party library like cublas (although the same principle applies to any cpu blas).

The problem is that there is a kind of stride between elements in the vector like so:

The matrix is stored as a 3Nx3N 1D array of floats.

The vector is stored as a N 1D array of float4s, but only the first three elements of each float4 are to be used, the fourth should be ignored.

N is in the order of millions.

If the vector were stored as float3 instead of float4 I could just cast the pointer to float, like in this working example:

```
//Compile with nvcc test.cu -O3 -lcublas -o test

/*
Multiply a 3Nx3N float matrix, M,  by a vector, X, of N float3 elements 

The result, Y, is a 3N float vector
-----------------------

What if X is a vector of N float4?

How can I tell cublas to skip the forth element?

*/

#include<iostream>
#include<thrust/device_vector.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<cublas_v2.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  int N = 3;

  thrust::device_vector<float3> X(N);

  thrust::device_vector<float> Y(3*N);

  for(int i=0; i<N; i++) 
     X[i] = make_float3(1,1,1); //make_float4(1,1,1,0); //in the case of float4 i.e., The result should be the same 

  thrust::device_vector<float> M(3*N*3*N, 1);


  cublasHandle_t handle;

  cublasCreate(&handle);

  float beta = 0.0f;
  float alpha = 1.0f;
  cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T,
          3*N, 3*N,
          &alpha,
          thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&M[0]), 3*N,
          (float*) thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&X[0]), 1,
          &beta,
          thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&Y[0]), 1);

  cout<<"Performed Y = M·X\n\tX = ";
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    float3 Xi = X[i];
    cout<<Xi.x<<" "<<Xi.y<<" "<<Xi.z<<" ";
  }  
  cout<<"\n\tY = ";
  for(int i=0; i<3*N; i++){
    cout<<Y[i]<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But, how can I perform this operation if the X vector is stored as float4 s?

Given that float4* can be interpreted as a float* with 4 times more elements, the question could be more general (although I am only interested in the float4 case);
If there is a stride between each 3 "useful" elements. I want to say to cublas that the array is not coalescent in memory. But something like: There is 3 elements at the start, the next three are "stride" elements after that, etc.
Similar to what you can do in OpenGL whith vertex array objects.

**EDIT:**

**The answers suggested that the most viable method is to just copy the strided array into a temporal, transformed, float3 array that cublas understands**.

The two options at the moment to do so are:

```
1. Use cudaMemcpy2D
2. Use a thrust transformation
3. Use a custom copy kernel
```

I wrote this code to test the three cases:

```
//Compile with Compile with: nvcc test.cu -O3 -lcublas -o test
#include<iostream>
#include<thrust/device_vector.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<cublas_v2.h>

using namespace std;


struct Timer{
  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  float time;

  void tic(){
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
  }
  float toc(){
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);

    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);

    return time;
  }

};



struct copy_functor{
  copy_functor(){}
  __device__ float3 operator() (const float4& X4){
    return make_float3(X4.x, X4.y, X4.z);
  }
};


__global__ void copy_kernel(const float4* __restrict__ X4, float3* __restrict__ X3, int N){
  int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if(id < N){
    float4 x4 = X4[id];
    X3[id] = make_float3(x4.x, x4.y, x4.z);
  }
}

int main(){

  int N = 1000000;
  int Ntest = 1000;

  Timer t;

  thrust::device_vector<float3> X3(N, make_float3(0,0,0));
  thrust::device_vector<float4> X4(N, make_float4(1,1,1,10));


  /*************************CUDAMEMCPY2D*******************/
  t.tic();

  for(int i= 0; i<Ntest; i++){
    cudaMemcpy2DAsync(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&X3[0]),
              3*sizeof(float),
              thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&X4[0]),
              4*sizeof(float),
              3*sizeof(float),
              N,
              cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();
   }
   printf ("Time for cudaMemcpy2DAsync: %f ms\n", t.toc()/(float)Ntest);


   /************************THRUST***********************/
   t.tic();

   for(int i= 0; i<Ntest; i++){
     transform(X4.begin(), X4.end(), X3.begin(), copy_functor());  
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();
   }

   printf ("Time for thrust transformation: %f ms\n", t.toc()/(float)Ntest);

   /*********************COPY KERNEL*****************************/

   t.tic();
   for(int i= 0; i<Ntest; i++){
     copy_kernel<<< N/128 + 1, 128 >>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&X4[0]),
                       thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&X3[0]), N);
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();
   }
   printf ("Time for copy kernel: %f ms\n", t.toc()/(float)Ntest);


return 0;
}
```

Notice that I am performing the mean of 1000 copies.

The output of this code in a GTX 980 is the following:

```
Time for cudaMemcpy2DAsync: 1.465522 ms
Time for thrust transformation: 0.178745 ms
Time for copy kernel: 0.168507 ms
```

cudaMemcpy2D is an order of magnitude more slow than the rest.

**thrust and copy kernel are very similar and the fastest way**

This behavior appears to remain with any number of elements.

**EDIT2:**

**Other answers suggest that GEMM could be used to communicate the stride.** Without the need for a temporal array.

Interpreting the Matrix vector mul. as a Matrix Matrix mul. would be done like so:

```
 cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_T,
              3*N, 1 /*m*/, 3*N,
              &alpha,
              thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&M[0]), 3*N,
              (float*) thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&X3[0]), 1 /*ldb*/,
              &beta,
              thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&Y[0]), 3*N);
```

However, at this point, I do not know how to pass X4 instead of X3. The solution appears to be in the m and ldb parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could treat your 1-D float4 vector as a Nx3 2-D float matrix with a row stride of 4, and use [`cudaMemcpy2DAsync`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge529b926e8fb574c2666a9a1d58b0dc1) to change the stride from 4 to 3 with

```
cudaMemcpy2DAsync(dst,
                  3*sizeof(float),
                  src,
                  4*sizeof(float),
                  3*sizeof(float),
                  N,
                  cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

Then the `dst` can be treated as a 3N 1-D float vector and passed to `gemv()` directly.

Given the scale of your `N`, the time of copying is not noticeable compared to `gemv()`.

---

**EDIT**

Benchmark result from @Apo shows that it is better to use a copy kernel instead of `cudaMemcpy2DAsync`. I was over-expected on `cudaMemcpy2DAsync` and thought it would be well optimized and have best performance for all cases.

Comment: Oh that is a sweet trick!. I was currently copying dst into src using a thrust transformation, but a cudaMemcpyAsync will sure be better!

Comment: You could also use `gemm` instead of `gemv` and supply the stride to the BLAS routine without the need for explicit copying

Comment: @talonmies using `gemm` can not get the same result.

Comment: I suggest to benchmark the cudaMemcpy2DAsync code and the thrust transformation code and maybe a regular CUDA kernel for the transform. PCIe has a high overhead when performing small transfers and that cudaMemcpy2DAsync will potentially do the copy with many ineffective 12 byte transfers. PCIe bandwidth is also significantly lower than GPU DRAM bandwidth. Copying the data with a regular gapless 1D transfer and then using a kernel to transform the data to 4 floats could easily be faster than the cudaMemcpy2DAsync transfer.

Comment: Thanks @jan , I believe you are totally right, see my question edit, where I test both cases.
Eric , Why do you think the gemm trick wont work?

Comment: @JanLucas It is a D2D copy. should have nothing to do with PCIe.

Comment: @Apo It seems many people support the possible `gemm()` approach. But I cannot imagine how you can get the same mathematical result  with `gemm()`. Anyone has any hints?

Comment: A vector is simply an extreme case of a matrix (with one dimension being 1). `*GEMM` supports strided access via the "leading dimension" arguments. So here the leading dimension would be 4, but the matrix dimension would be 3, effectively skipping every fourth element. Using `*GEMM` for matrix-vector multiplications is not a high performance approach, but given that the alternative is strided copies, which are also slow, it may be worth a try.

Comment: @njuffa The original problem is a mat-vec-mul like `vec_result(3N) = mat(3N, 3N) * vec(3N)`. The result vec is of the length 3N. But with `gemm()`, it is like trying to do `mat(3N, 3N) * mat(3, N)`. Those two matrices don't have a common dimension, and you can not get a result vec(3N) or even a mat(3, N) which may be reshaped later to a vec(3N)...

Comment: @Eric That's what the "transpose" attributes of `*GEMM` are for, or am I missing something?

Comment: @njuffa long story.. it's a math problem not programming. hard to explain with my poor english.

Comment: @Eric: I do understand matrix multiplication and I have written `*GEMM` implementations. The transpose options of `*GEMM` allow for the *implicit* transposition of the matrices, thus achieving the required matching of dimensions. It is possible I am overlooking something on the quick here, but it seems to me talomies's proposal has merit if you look at appropriately configured batched `*GEMM` calls.

Comment: @njuffa I've thought about a lot of possibilities. But I still think it is not possible, even with batched `gemm()`. though it is hard to prove that. I will be happy if someone can give a solution to prove that I'm wrong.

Comment: Eric, I think the cudaMemcpy2D is copying the "2D" matrix column by column. As in this case a "column" has only 3 elements, it is performing N 12 bytes transfers, as I believe @Jan was suggesting.

Comment: @njuffa , talonmies I cannot get my head around the GEMM approach, I get the idea, but I do not completly understand the leading dimension term.     The matrix sizes in GEMM (m, n and k) would be 3N,1,3N. So the operation is   C(3Nx1) = A(3Nx3N )· B(1x3N).  I do not see how the leading dimension of B can be anything but 1. Could you give me more hints?, please see my edit in the question.

Comment: @Eric: Ah right, then it is likely fine. I assumed it was host->device without checking.

Comment: @Apo `cudaMemcpy2D` should have done better, if thrust::transform can easily reach the peak performance.